# How do I create multiple steps in this function without explicitly specifying the number of steps?

Tags: bash

in this case `$@` could contain any number of args from 0-100. I need to add a `step` into my `do-something` function code for each of these args. I bet there's already an answer for this but I'm not sure what to call this or how to google this. Thanks

```
echo $@
```

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

```
do-something \
--step 1 \
--step 2 \
--step 3 \
--step 4 \
--step 5 \
```

Comment: I'm confused... did you already write the code that implements do-something?  Are you asking how to take a string "1 2" and transform it into "--step 1 --step 2"?

Comment: The answer below describes it.

Comment: Ok, do you're not "adding a step into the do-something function code" since the code for that function already exists somewhere else.  What you're really doing is adding `--step` arguments to a command string that *calls* do-something.

Answer (score 2):

You can build an array with all the `--step` options:

```
args=()
for step in "$@"; do
    args+=(--step "$step")
done
```

Then call `do-something` like so:

```
do-something "${args[@]}"
```